# Python Memoization failing on Leetcode

Tags: python

**The Scenario:**

I am doing a question on Leetcode called nth Ugly Number. The algorithm is to find the nth number whose prime factors include only 1, 2, 3, and 5.

I created a solution which was accepted and passed all the tests. Then, I wanted to memoize it for practice with memoization with python - however, something has gone wrong with the memoization. It works for my own personal tests, but Leetcode does not accept the answer.

The memoized code is detailed below:

```
class Solution:
    uglyNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    latest2index = 2
    latest3index = 1
    latest5index = 1
        
    def nthUglyNumber(self, n: int) -> int:
        while len(self.uglyNumbers) <= n:
            
            guess2 = self.uglyNumbers[self.latest2index] * 2
            guess3 = self.uglyNumbers[self.latest3index] * 3
            guess5 = self.uglyNumbers[self.latest5index] * 5
            
            nextUgly = min(guess2, guess3, guess5)
            if(nextUgly == guess2):
                self.latest2index += 1
            if(nextUgly == guess3):
                self.latest3index += 1
            if(nextUgly == guess5):
                self.latest5index += 1
                
            self.uglyNumbers.append(nextUgly)
            
        return self.uglyNumbers[n-1]
```

The only change I made when memoizing was to make uglyNumbers, latest2index, etc. to be class members instead of local variables.

**The Problem:**

When I submit to LeetCode, it claims that the solution no longer works. Here is where it breaks:

> Input 12  /// Output 6  /// Expected 16

However, when I test the code myself and provide it with input 12, it gives the expected output 16. It does this even if I call nthUglyNumber with a bunch of different inputs before and after 12, so I have no idea why the test case breaks upon being submitted to LeetCode

Here's the testing I performed to confirm that the algorithm appears to work as expected:

```
# This code goes inside Class Solution
    def nthUglyNumber(self, n: int) -> int:
        print("10th: " + str(self.nthUgliNumber(10)))
        print("11th: " + str(self.nthUgliNumber(11)))
        print("12th: " + str(self.nthUgliNumber(12)))
        print("9th: " + str(self.nthUgliNumber(9)))
        print("14th: " + str(self.nthUgliNumber(14)))
        print("10th: " + str(self.nthUgliNumber(10)))
        print("11th: " + str(self.nthUgliNumber(11)))
        print("12th: " + str(self.nthUgliNumber(12)))
        return self.nthUgliNumber(n)
    def nthUgliNumber(self, n: int) -> int:
# The regular definition of nthUglyNumber goes here
```

**What I want to know**

Is there some edge case in Python memoization that I am not seeing that's causing the code to trip up? Or is it fully Leetcode's fault? I know my algorithm works without memoization, but I want to understand what's going wrong so I gain a better understanding of Python and so that I can avoid similar mistakes in the future.
I appreciate the help!

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the class variables.  Maybe leetcode is creating many instances of `Solution`?  What effect would that have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe leetcode is probably running all tests in parallel on multiple threads using separate instances of the Solution class.  Since you are storing `nthUgliNumber` as a class variable, instances may be updating it (and the 3 indexes) in a conflicting manner.

From leetcode's perspective, each test is not expected to have side effects that would impact other tests. So, parallel execution in distinct instances is legitimate. Caching beyond the scope of the test case is likely undesirable as it would make performance measurements inconsistent and dependent on the order and content of the test cases.